# Division on a list of multivariate XTS without for loop

Tags: r, xts

I have a list of 2 column XTS's and I want to divide the second column of each XTS by a 3rd XTS, and store the results back in the second column.  I am currently using a for loop to do this:

```
for(i in 1:length(data)){
  data[[i]][,2] <- data[[i]][,2] / temp
}
```

`temp` is a single column XTS and it is sometimes longer that the XTS in data, sometimes not but they do definitely overlap.

How can I do this without the for loop?

Comment: So is `data` a list of `xts` objects?

Comment: Can you give sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking shot without proper sample data. If you provide sample data, I will update answer accordingly.

For timeseries, IMO, right way to do division will be of values which correspond to same timestamp. To do that you should first `merge` the `temp` xts timeseries with each element of your list object `data` and then do the division. To do this, you can use `lapply` and custom function `div` as defined below.

```
div <- function(x) {
    x <- merge(x,temp)
    x[,2] <- x[,2] / x[,3]
}

lapply(X = data, FUN = div)
```